# How to find time differences between two time in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a form that gives me time_in and time_out hours of all staff members. Time_in and time_out also  sql tables. Basically form returns the database table values. What I would like to do is to display the work hour of them. Work hour can be get the differences from time_out to time_in. I have two text boxes that display time in and Time_out. The third one should display work hour.

Here is what I have for time_out value for Wednesday:

```
//Selected TimeOutWednesday
        SqlCommand TimeOutWednesdayMain = cs.CreateCommand();
        TimeOutWednesdayMain.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time_out, 108) AS time_out  FROM job_punch_card  WHERE emp_key='" + listBoxNames.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'and punch_day= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 2)";
        Object TimeOutWednesdayMainTemp = TimeOutWednesdayMain.ExecuteScalar();
        txtTimeInWed.Text = TimeOutWednesdayMainTemp.ToString();
```

This code gives me time_out for wednesday for the selected user from my listbox. I have the same code for time_in as well. What I couldn't do is to figure out how find the work hour? How can I display their work hour in a label or text box like I have above?

Comment: Why not use a query that pulls the time in, time out, and the difference in hours?  Also I assume `time_in` and `time_out` are `DateTime`, is that correct?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection

Comment: Correct. How to get the difference in sql ?

Comment: In SQL, you can get the hour by doing `DATEPART(HOUR, time_out)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTime types in OS are simples Integer values, you should make a arithmetical operation and get the Hours or TotalHours:

Hours get the integer portion of difference (dont lose parse your textboxes):

```
DateTime time_in;
DateTime.TryParse(time_in_TextBox.Text, out time_in);

DateTime time_out;
DateTime.TryParse(time_out_TextBox.Text, out time_out);

int hours = (time_in - time_out).Hours;
```

TotalHours get a double value with the exact difference in DateTimes:

```
DateTime time_in;
DateTime.TryParse(time_in_TextBox.Text, out time_in);

DateTime time_out;
DateTime.TryParse(time_out_TextBox.Text, out time_out);

double totalHours = (time_in - time_out).TotalHours;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. All the answers work but this one seems easy to me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're set on doing the time difference in SQL, but here's how you can do it in C# - though you would need to convert to a datetime object, not just a time (at least in this example).

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/DSuHmH :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1);
        DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 5, 10, 55);

        TimeSpan ts = endTime - startTime;

        Console.WriteLine(ts); // returns "04:05:54"
    }
}
```

to specifically get the hours use:

```
ts.Hours;
```

To accomplish in sql you can do something like the following - again you'll need to convert your time to a datetime and then you can utilize the datediff function.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7a7c/7

```
select convert(datetime, '2014-01-01 ' + startTime, 101),
       convert(datetime, '2014-01-01 ' + endTime, 101),
       datediff(
           hh, 
           convert(datetime, '2014-01-01 ' + startTime, 101), 
           convert(datetime, '2014-01-01 ' + endTime, 101)
       )
from test
```

Note that in the examples above i'm using an arbitrary date to accomplish creating a valid datetime

Comment: Yeah. I have to retrieve the start and end time from sql server.

Comment: Note that `TimeSpan.Hours` get the hours part of the `TimeSpan`.  The OP might want to use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` instead.

Comment: @Karatay you can still do that in this case it was just meant to be used as an example

Answer (score 2):

You can get the time difference, in minutes, using this:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @punch_day, @time_out)
```

This will return the total minutes between the two dates. If you need hours, divide it by `60`. If you need days, then divide it by `(60*24)`. Should you need weeks, divide it by `(60*24*7)`. If you need years, divide it by `(60*24*365)`. You get the idea, I hope!

Check out this example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = '12/9/2014 11:04am'
SELECT @EndDate = '12/10/2014 1:38pm'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS TotalMinutes, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60 AS TotalHours,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / (60*24) AS TotalDays
```

Comment: why not just use `datediff(hh....)` in this instance rather than calculating hours based on minutes?  is it partial hours you're looking at?

Comment: @Kritner -- He could, but I am assuming he'll want it in minutes so that he can calculate left over minutes using the modulus operator `%`. Plus this way, he's only doing one hit to the database server, vs one hit for hours, one hit for minutes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in one query.  This also shows the best practices for dealing with ADO.Net including putting your sql objects in using statements and passing values into your query as a parameter.  Additionally you'll have to use `ExecuteReader` to get more than one value back and you can add checking for retrieving more or less than 1 row.

```
using (var cs = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    cs.Open();
    using (var command = cs.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT 
                  time_in, 
                  time_out, 
                  DATEDIFF(minute, time_in, time_out) As minutesWorked 
              FROM job_punch_card  
              WHERE emp_key=@EMPKEY 
                    and punch_day= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 2)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@EMPKEY", 
            listBoxNames.SelectedValue.ToString());

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                // There was no match for your key
            }

            reader.Read();

            DateTime timeIn = reader.GetDateTime(0);
            DateTime timeOut = reader.GetDateTime(1);
            int minutesWorked = reader.GetInt32(2);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                // There was more than one match on key
            }
        }
    }
}
```